# Finding NaNs in a really large binary data file

Tags: bash, search, fortran, nan, binary-data

I have a file produced by a `Fortran` code.  An working on a Linux platform in bash.  The file is 5GB+ in size.  I suspect there is a `NaN` hiding in it somewhere and am trying to find it.  All I know to do is pipe the output of `od` into `less` and then do a search.  This process is taking a really long time to go through the file.  Anyone have a faster way to do it?

Comment: Write another Fortran (or C or whatever other faster language you like) program that's aware of the format that can scan it for the values you care about.

Comment: shell script is not good at dealing with binary files. its even harder to make shell understand your binary file's record format.

Comment: Also, remember that there are multiple bit patterns (byte sequences) that all represent a NaN. And endianness also matters. I would just use a Fortran, C(++) or Python program and not shell.